# Postgres: Subquery with GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to optimize a query (instead of repeating it a lot of time), with this **NOT FUNCTIONAL CODE** above (since subqueries only return 1 column):

```sql
SELECT
    e.pageview_identifier,
    e.created_at,
    e.pageview_current_url,
    e.pageview_mobile,
    (
        SELECT event_type, COUNT(event_identifier)
        FROM events v
        WHERE
            v.company_identifier = e.company_identifier AND
            v.user_identifier = e.user_identifier AND
            v.pageview_identifier = e.pageview_identifier
        GROUP BY v.event_type
    )
FROM events e
WHERE
    company_identifier = 'xyz' AND
    user_identifier = '01CDQZVSJFBDA8W444JS2CS3BA' AND
    event_type = 'page:view';
```

Basically, I want to retrieve the columns as

```
pageview_identifier, created_at, ..., event_type_a_count, event_type_b_count, ...
```

A **FUNCTIONAL** code that works is:

```
SELECT
    e.pageview_identifier,
    e.created_at,
    e.pageview_current_url,
    e.pageview_mobile,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(event_identifier)
        FROM events v
        WHERE
            v.company_identifier = e.company_identifier AND
            v.user_identifier = e.user_identifier AND
            v.pageview_identifier = e.pageview_identifier AND
            v.event_type = 'mouse:move'
    ) as mouse_move_count
FROM events e
WHERE
    company_identifier = 'xyz' AND
    user_identifier = '01CDQZVSJFBDA8W444JS2CS3BA' AND
    event_type = 'page:view';
```

But in this case, I would need to repeat a lot of time this subquery for each kind of `event_type`.

Answer (score 3):

Was solved using window functions, like:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT e.pageview_identifier,
             e.created_at,
             e.pageview_current_url,
             e.pageview_mobile,
             e.event_type,
             COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE e.event_type = 'mouse:move') OVER (PARTITION BY e.company_identifier, e.user_identifier, e.pageview_identifier) as cnt_mouse_move,
             ...
      FROM events e
      WHERE e.company_identifier = 'xyz' AND
          e.user_identifier = '01CDQZVSJFBDA8W444JS2CS3BA' 
     ) e
WHERE e.event_type = 'page:view';
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. +1 for posting a solution that you came up with for your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only one table involved a window function like you suggest is probably the way to go. For a more general case where the sub-select involves a different table, a LATERAL JOIN often comes handy:

```
SELECT
    e.pageview_identifier,
    e.created_at,
    e.pageview_current_url,
    e.pageview_mobile,
    mmc.event_type,
    mmc.cnt
FROM events e
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT event_type, COUNT(event_identifier) as cnt
    FROM whatever v
    WHERE v.company_identifier = e.company_identifier 
      AND v.user_identifier = e.user_identifier 
      AND v.pageview_identifier = e.pageview_identifier
    GROUP BY v.event_type    
) as mmc
```

LATERAL is a construction that makes it possible to reference a previously declared "sibling" table. You can express the same thing with a usual join (moving the where to the on clause), but it can often be beneficial performance-wise to push the predicates inside the sub-select to avoid evaluating the count for a lot of rows that will be later discarded by the join condition. In an ideal world, the optimizer would be able to do this on its own, but in many situations, it won't.